# How to refer to a data.frame variable in a dplyr pipeline via . programmatically?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

data <- data.frame(THEME_NAME = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 20), rep("C", 15)))

data %>%
  group_by(THEME_NAME) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  # THE NEXT LINE !!! #
  ggplot(., aes(x = reorder(THEME_NAME, desc(freq)), y = freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

How can I refer to `THEME_NAME` programmatically?  I can do `.$THEME_NAME`, but I'd like to refer to as `.[1]` or `select(., 1)` or something to that nature?

The reason for this is I'd like to use this pipeline in a bigger context - such as passing a bunch of factor variables through this pipeline.  Something like: `vars.to.plot <- sapply(data, is.factor)` and then running each element of `vars.to.plot` through this pipeline.

Comment: For starters, `ggplot(., aes_string(x = names(.)[1L], y = "freq"))` works, but I haven't figured out how to use this together with the `reorder` inside `ggplot`.

Comment: Thanks @docendodiscimus +1 - The more I think about this, I think there's just got a be a better way; maybe something outputting a list up front and then `do` or `do.call` or `lapply`. I might tweak the example to detail another factor variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideas shared here are useful, but this is what I actually ended up doing:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

data <- data.frame(THEME_NAME   = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 20), rep("C", 15)),
                   THEME_NAME_2 = c(rep("E", 5), rep("F", 40)),
                   Non_Factor   = 1:45)

factor.vars <- sapply(data, is.factor)
varnames    <- names(data)[factor.vars]

myReorder <- function(x) {
  factor(x, levels=names(sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE)))
}


for (i in seq_along(varnames)) {
  data[, varnames[i]] <- myReorder(data[, varnames[i]])
}


for (i in seq_along(varnames)) {
  print(ggplot(data, aes_string(x = varnames[i], y = "..count../sum(..count..)")) + 
          geom_histogram())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So you need to setup a variable to hold the name of the grouping variable because the "group by" variable information isn't preserved in the `tbl_df` object after the `summarize()` call apparently. You could do this

```
varname<-"THEME_NAME"

data %>%
  group_by_(varname) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(eval(bquote(aes(x=reorder(.(as.name(varname)), desc(freq)), y=freq)))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

Here use use `bquote()` to dynamically build the `aes()` call. This is only necessary because of the `reorder()` step you want to do. Otherwise it would be much easier with an `aes_string()` or something.

If you always wanted to re-order based on the first column (meaning you would never group by more than one variable), you could do

```
data %>%
  group_by(THEME_NAME) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  {ggplot(., eval(substitute(aes(x=reorder(X, desc(freq)), y=freq), list(X=as.name(names(.)[1])))))  +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)}
```

which doesn't require

Comment: +1 and I will eventually mark this as answered, but I'm curious to see if someone else can come up with something more elegant.

Comment: I just added an alternate method which picks off the first column rather than using a variable.

Comment: Yep, saw that and that's a nice option, but "future me" will probably be lost if I read that code later.

Comment: If you're still there, check the more elaborate example above that doesn't work 100%, but gets at the heart of the issue and introduces more problems with not printing the `ggplot` object, but we're getting off topic...

Comment: Well, objects in loops aren't printed by default so you'll need to explicitly call `print()`. Not sure what the other problems you might be having.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this must be done in three parts.  There are a few limitations I discovered that I would appreciate someone correcting if I am mistaken.

```
data <- data.frame(THEME_NAME = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 20), rep("C", 15)))    
my_var <- names(data)[1]

df <- data %>%
  group_by_(my_var) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(freq))

df[[1]] <- factor(df[[1]], levels = unique(df[[1]]))

ggplot(df, aes_string(x = my_var, y = "freq")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

Trying to have it all one call I ran in to these problems:

1. There is no way to prevent `ggplot` from ordering the x-axis automatically without resetting the levels of you variable prior to the call.  The only way within the `ggplot` call is with `reorder` which cannot, to my knowledge, be used with `aes_string`.
2. Another idea I had was to use `mutate` to reset the levels.  One would need to use the `s_mutate` function from `dplyrExras` to use strings but resetting levels from the piped dataset doesn't appear to work strings.

The statement would look with `mutate` like this (which works BTW):

```
mutate(THEME_NAME = factor(THEME_NAME, levels=unique(THEME_NAME)))
```

but with the string accepting version the levels remain the same:

```
s_mutate(my_var = factor(my_var, levels = unique(my_var)))
```